# Call parent constructor with this as argument

Tags: scala

I have a class that takes one of its subclasses as an argument. When constructing that subclass, I want to be able to use `this` as the value of that argument:

```
class A(val b: B)

class B extends A(this)
```

However, this fails to compile

```
this can be used only in a class, object, or template
[error] class B extends A(this)
[error]                   ^
```

Is there any way to get around this? I'm pretty sure that a pattern like this can be written in Java.

Comment: This really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure about the last statement:

```
public class MyClass {
    static class A {
        A(B b) {
            System.out.println(b.value);
        }
    }
    static class B extends A {
        String value;;
        B() {
            super(this);
            value = "x";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new B();
    }
}
```

gives the following error:

```
/MyClass.java:10: error: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called
            super(this);
                  ^
```

There is no good reason to attempt to let the `this` reference escape the scope of the constructor before the object itself has been constructed. Refactor it.

Comment: My `A` was represented by ≥ 1 `B`s, so I wanted `B` to be its own canonical representation. You're right that it doesn't seem to be possible in Java either though, so I will find an alternative representation.